# Log batch to logfile

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

simple batch that copy and delete file and log to destination network share, the problem is that in log I have only that files were copied there is nothing that files on destination were deleted

```
md \\network share\"%date%"\
set LOGFILE=\\network share\"%date%"\"%date%"_"log".log
call :LOG > %LOGFILE%
exit /B

:LOG
Xcopy /E /Y C:\source\*.* \\network share\"%date%"\
del C:\source\*.bak /Q
```

and the log file have only:

```
C:\source\1.bak
C:\source\2.bak
2 File(s) copied
```

Answer (score 0):

The `del` command doesn't produce any output. You should use `robocopy`, or some powershell command like `Remove-Item`:

```
remove-item .\2021.zip -verbose
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "C:\Users\gasperc\2021.zip".
```

Answer (score 0):

```bath
for /f delims^= %%i in ('dir /a:-d /b "C:\source\*.bak"
')do del /q "%%~fi" && echo\ Deleted: "%%~dpi" "%%~nxi"
```

---

You can use a `for` loop to delete one by one and get "custom" output as you wish.

```bath
@echo off 

md "\\network share\%date%\"
set "LOGFILE=\\network share\%date%\%date%_log.log"

call :LOG > "%LOGFILE%" & exit /B

:LOG
Xcopy /E /Y "C:\source\*.*" "\\network share\%date%\"

for /f delims^= %%i in ('dir /a:-d /b "C:\source\*.bak"
')do del /q "%%~fi" && echo\ Deleted: "%%~dpi" "%%~nxi"
```

---

## Additional Resources:

- **[`Dir /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)**
- **[`Echo /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html)**
- **[`For /?` Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)**
- **[`For /F /?` Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**
- **[Conditional Execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**

  - **[`||`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)** and **[`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**